# Type.GetField on array field returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I'm trying to get an array field from class using Reflections. On a simple field it works, on Array it doesn't.

This is the class

```
public abstract class Condition : ScriptableObject
{
    public string Name;
    public virtual bool IsVerified() { return false; }
}

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Condition _condition = null;
    [SerializeField] Condition[] _conditions = new Condition[0];
}

[CustomPropertyDrawer(typeof(Condition))]
public class ConditionPropertyDrawer : PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect position, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        EditorGUI.BeginProperty(position, label, property);

        Type propertyType = GetPropertyType(property);

        EditorGUI.EndProperty();
    }

    private Type GetPropertyType(SerializedProperty property)
    {
        Type parentType = property.serializedObject.targetObject.GetType();
        Debug.Log($"{parentType} => {property.propertyPath}");
        FieldInfo fi = parentType.GetField(property.propertyPath, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        Debug.Log(fi);
        return fi.FieldType;
    }
}
```

This is where I'm getting Fields:

```
Type parentType = property.serializedObject.targetObject.GetType();
Debug.Log($"{parentType} => {property.propertyPath}");
FieldInfo fi = parentType.GetField(property.propertyPath, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
Debug.Log(fi);
```

The Debug prints (Condition var):

> ExampleScript => _condition
> MyFullNameSpace.Condition _condition

The Debug prints (Condition[] var):

> ExampleScript => _conditions.Array.data[0]
> Null

Why it doesn't return right FieldInfo?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You appear to be trying to get a field called `"_conditions.Array.data[0]"`. You don't have such a field. (We have no context for where you're getting `property.propertyPath` from, which makes it hard to help any further.)

Comment: (If you could provide a [mcve], it would generally be a lot easier to help you. From what you've shown, it really *looks* like this has everything to do with trying to use a value which isn't the name of a field. If the reality is more complex - well, that's where a minimal example helps to clarify things.)

Comment: `SerializedProperty.propertyPath` is the path relates to the `SerializedObject`, it's not the path of the field.

Answer (score 0):

`GetField(property.propertyPath, ...)` doesnt work, because it does not take a path. It takes only the `property-name`. You get the property at the end of a path by splitting the pathString at the dots - find the `first object` in the base - Then the `second object` in the `first object` ...

Keep in mind, that the path `warns` you with the keyword Array, if a collection is coming. Your path is there something like `class1.class2.Array.data[i].class3`  So dont search in class 2 for a property named `Array`. Instead cast the object to `IEnumerable` and get the `i item`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).